# How To Perform Action Within Time Interval

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to change the text of a label according to the time of the day.

```cs
Label OpenClosedLabel = new Label();
TimeSpan T1 = new TimeSpan(13, 00, 00);
TimeSpan T2 = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 00);
```

Now, if the `DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay` is within `T1` and `T2` the label should be "Open" else it should be "Closed".

I have tried this, but it doesnt work:

```cs
if (DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay >= T1 && DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay <= T2)
{ 
    OpenClosedLabel.Text = "Open";
} 
else
{ 
    OpenClosedLabel.Text = "Closed";
}
```

Comment: Is this a mobile app?

Comment: @SeM yes it is .

Comment: So what's the problem, add if condition and check whether today's time of the day is within the given range.

Comment: @SeM, i tried something like this `if (DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay >= T1 & DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay <=T2 {}` buut i was not working.

Comment: `DateTime.Today` will only have the date. `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` will have the time

Comment: Also based on your use case you may want `DateTime.NowUtc.TimeOfDay`

Comment: What you mean it's not working, what time are you comparing? Have in mind, that, for example, `13:00:01` is not less than `00:00:00` (you may want to use `23:59:59` instead).

Comment: No worries, easy mistake to make! I have done it tons of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay` will only give you the date but

`DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay` will give you the time data too.

So, I would do it like so:

```cs
Label OpenClosedLabel = new Label();
TimeSpan T1 = new TimeSpan(13, 00, 00);
TimeSpan T2 = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
var Now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
OpenClosedLabel.Text = (Now >= T1 && Now <= T2) ? "Open" : "Closed";
```